# How to interpret regressors when the dependent variable is standardized?

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, standardization

How to interpret the regressors coefficients when the dependent variable is standardized?

Comment: Have you checked out [our related answers on this subject](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+standardized+dependent+answers%3A1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the standardization has involved multiplying the dependent variable by a constant, C, then the regressors' coefficients you get are those you would get if you estimated the model with no standardization and then multiplied the resulting coefficients by C.

The only exception is the intercept, which is additionally effect by any constant, A, added to the dependent variable.